# k8s persistent volume (PV) data gets deleted after pod recreation with all ReclaimPolicy : Retain

Tags: kubernetes, flink-streaming, kubernetes-pvc, flink-state

**What happened?**
I created one `PV(persistent volume)` using .yaml file 10G on aws efs `/data/flink/state`
created PVC of 10G and here we are using dynamic provisioning (`storage-class`) to mount PV.
created pod deployment using deploy.yaml file. here we are using FlinkOperator to deploy the application. Here we are uing flink 1.16
entered to pod using

```
kubectl exec -it flow-engine-598f45f7d6-qqv9p -- bash
```

to access the bash of the pod created.
Run the flink application which created the file on above mentioned path i.e `/data/flink/state`
now deleted the pod using

```
kubectl delete pod flow-engine-598f45f7d6-qqv9p
```

now again new pod gets created after deleting the above pod and I accessed the bash of the new pod again
And I don't see a file created inside the mount path `/data/flink/state`, this file got deleted.
What happened:
after every deletion of the pod, the data will get deleted from that mounted path.

**What we expected to happen:**
Retain policy: data should be available after every pod recreation unless PV is deleted. And we can able to fetch that data.

Comment: Can you show us your PVC and Deployment manifests? Deleting a Pod should not delete the PV.